# How to "left-center" align wrapped inline-blocks within a div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, alignment

I've seen some similar questions to this, but most seem to lack images that thoroughly display what the problem is.

I'm trying to get the following responsive layout to work when narrow.  It looks like this right now:

[image]

Here's what I want it to look like.  Note that the left edge of the fields and labels are aligned with each other, but all together they are centered relative to everything else.

[image]

And finally, here's what it has to look like when the parent div is wide (this is working):

[image]

Here's my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <style type="text/css">
    .CalibrationPointStep {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .CalibrationPointStep > .table {
      display: table;
      text-align: left;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

    .CalibrationPointStep > .table > .raw {
      margin-right: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .CalibrationPointStep > .table > .raw,
    .CalibrationPointStep > .table > .actual {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .CalibrationPointStep > .table > .raw > .header,
    .CalibrationPointStep > .table > .actual > .header {
      text-align: left;
      display: block;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .CalibrationPointStep > .table > .raw > .value {
    .CalibrationPointStep > .table > .actual > .value {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="CalibrationPointStep">
    <h3>Step 1</h3>
    <p>Go to a known low state, and enter the actual value.</p>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="raw">
        <div class="header">Raw Value</div>
        <div class="value">
          <input type="number" readOnly /> counts
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="actual">
        <div class="header">Actual Value</div>
        <div class="value">
          <input type="number" /> kips
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Note that if I remove `text-align: left` from `.CalibrationPointStep > .table` it looks like this, which I don't want either:

[image]

It seems like the problem is that when one of the inline-block divs has to wrap, the width of the parent div truncates to the maximum available, rather than the minimum width spanning its children.

If possible I want a solution that works in IE8+.  But if that's not possible I'm still curious about solutions for more modern browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.CalibrationPointStep {
    text-align: center;
}
.raw,
.actual {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.header,
.value {
    text-align: left;
}
.header {
    font-weight: bold;
}
input {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u45s9uaz/1/).

Also, in actual projects, you don't want to pile up all the CSS selectors  for an element as it will make your CSS unnecessarily complicated, therefore hard to organize and maintain. In most cases, just pick one most appropriate and descriptive class will be enough.

Comment: Oh, I see.  But is there a way to do it without fixed widths, so that it will work perfectly for any units text following the input ("counts", "kips", "gallons/min", etc.)  I'm never 100% happy with hard-coded dimensions in CSS, especially when trying to do responsive layouts...in my desktop programming days I never needed such hacks to fix a layout issue, since I could perform the layout in actual code.

Comment: Or is there a way to make all of the divs have the same width as the widest one?

Comment: And there were so many CSS selectors because I'm actually using React/Sass, and I'm trying to at least namespace all of my React components.  Hopefully eventually we'll get locally-scoped CSS from the web components revolution.

Comment: Well, responsive design mostly deals with the uncertainty of user device, not your content. You can, of course, change the fixed width to some percentage, say `40%`. But in this case you couldn't _both_ align the textfield and label center and align your label left to the textfield - because the actual width of your controls is unknown at design time.

Comment: There are three possible solutions I come up to the above situation: utilize some gird systems like `Bootstrap` does (which will give you some limited flexibility), use the CSS `calc` (which is not fully supported until IE10) or JavaScript to do some advanced layout.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that.  Would CSS calc somehow eliminate the need for any hard-coded or percentage dimensions?  I can't think of how, but maybe there's something I don't know about it.